# OpenCL/OpenGL interop wasting CPU

Tags: opengl, opencl

I generate frames in OpenCL 60 times per second using one OpenCL kernel call each time and write them to an OpenGL texture so that I can display them on the screen. There's no performance problem, the frame rate is as expected, the problem however is that it's very wasteful, it keeps at least one CPU core fully busy, even when it has very little to do, like drawing a blank frame at a very low resolution. For comparison when I don't use the OpenGL interop but instead write from the CL kernel to a generic buffer and then copy that buffer back to the host to then display it in another way the frame rate drops a bit (due to the back and forth overhead that the interop makes unnecessary) but then the CPU usage is much lower when there's little to do.

This means that there's something wrong with the way I do the interop that I assume must create some sort of busy wait.

Here's the relevant code, which is the code that is there when I use the interop and not there when I don't use it. In one place of my loop I clear the GL texture and make OpenCL acquire it:

```
    uint32_t z = 0;
    glClearTexImage(fb.gltex, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &z);
    glFlush();
    glFinish();

    clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects(fb.clctx.command_queue, 1,  &fb.cl_srgb, 0, 0, NULL);
```

Then I enqueue the execution of my OpenCL kernel which writes to the texture as the `cl_mem` object `fb.cl_srgb` and later I give control back to OpenGL in order to display the texture on the display:

```
    clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects(fb.clctx.command_queue, 1, &fb.cl_srgb, 0, 0, NULL);
    clFinish(fb.clctx.command_queue);   // this blocks until the kernel is done writing to the texture and releasing the texture

    // setting GL texture coordinates, probably not relevant to this question
    float hoff = 2. * (fb.h - fb.maxdim.y) / (double) fb.maxdim.y;
    glLoadIdentity();             // Reset the projection matrix
    glViewport(0, 0, fb.maxdim.x, fb.maxdim.y);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.f, 0.f); glVertex2f(-1., 1.+hoff);
    glTexCoord2f(1.f, 0.f); glVertex2f(1., 1.+hoff);
    glTexCoord2f(1.f, 1.f); glVertex2f(1., -1.+hoff);
    glTexCoord2f(0.f, 1.f); glVertex2f(-1., -1.+hoff);
    glEnd();

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(fb.window);
```

It's hard for me to tell what is causing it because the high CPU usage is in another thread ran by nvopencl64.dll (when I run it on my Windows 10 machine with an nVidia GPU, but I have a similar problem with a laptop with an Intel iGPU, also on Windows 10).

Profiling tells me that most of the CPU time is taken by `WaitForSingleObjectEx` (exclusive 42% of the CPU time) called from nvopencl64.dll, `WaitForMultipleObjects` (21%) called from nvoglv64.dll's `DrvPresentBuffers` and the `RtlUserThreadStart` (16%) calls that originate the aforementioned `WaitForMultipleObjects` calls. That's for my nVidia GPU machine, but the situation looks pretty similar on a machine with only an Intel HD 5000 iGPU. So there's clearly something very inefficient going on, probably with lots of threads being started way too often.

Comment: In case anyone wants to test this problem with my code I have a small project that demonstrates it, with a Windows binary available: https://github.com/Photosounder/rouziclib-picture-viewer/.

Comment: Seems like the GPU doesn\`t want you to do what you do. Does `clGetDeviceInfo(CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_INTEROP_USER_SYNC)` return `CL_FALSE`?

Comment: `clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_INTEROP_USER_SYNC, 0, NULL, &info_size);` returns 0, so what does it mean? The documentation says "CL_FALSE if the device / implementation has a performant path for performing synchronization of memory object shared between OpenCL and other APIs such as DirectX", I don't know what this implies.

Comment: Damn, I should\`ve specified that `param_value` needs to be a pointer to the `cl_bool` value to which the actual result gets written, and `param_value_size` needs to be set to `sizeof(cl_bool)`. The value returned directly from the function is not the result you need, and it being 0 just means that the call is successful, for it is to be interpreted as `CL_SUCCESS`.

Comment: OK well `cl_bool val;` `clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_INTEROP_USER_SYNC, sizeof(cl_bool), &val, &info_size);` gives me a `val` that is 0.

Comment: Okay, so your GPU doesn\`t require manual sync. Try removing `clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects` and `clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects` and see what happens. On a side note, are you using `clCreateFromGLTexture` to pass GL textures to CL?

Comment: When I try removing those two then `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` fails everytime (returns -1000 aka `CL_INVALID_GL_SHAREGROUP_REFERENCE_KHR`, there must be something missing in my code, do I have to activate some extension?), the kernel takes `fb.cl_srgb` as argument. `fb.cl_srgb` is a `cl_mem` initalised by `fb.cl_srgb = clCreateFromGLTexture(fb.clctx.context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, fb.gltex, &ret);` after the texture is initalised by OpenGL.

Comment: Now that\`s curious… Somewhere around tomorrow I`ll try and execute your code on my machine to see for myself.

Comment: Thank you! Did you get to build the code? Maybe the instructions I wrote aren't so clear. Anyway I just tried to follow the `clCreateFromGLTexture()` call with a single `clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects()` call with no further interop calls, that fixes the problem, giving me about only 2% of CPU usage (instead of 1 or 2 full cores) while still running at 60 FPS, which seems optimal. I guess that's what has to be done when `CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_INTEROP_USER_SYNC` gives us 0. Since you hinted at that solution and there's a bounty you should write the answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem that efficient anymore when it has something to draw (like when having a picture showing in the picture viewer as opposed to not showing), a lot of `WaitForSingleObjectEx`, `WaitForMultipleObjects` and `RtlUserThreadStart` going on again, which probably has something to do with the kernel taking longer to run and the CPU keeping busy to wait for it to return. Although it seems to help to remove calls to `clFinish` and `glFinish`, is this the right thing to do? Probably not, it seems to make things jittery, as if frames were skipped.

Comment: It seems that only `glFinish` is needed, at least on this machine. For the sake of testing on other systems I've added this dialog https://i.imgur.com/u4a2g06.png to the minimal picture viewer example (press Alt-D a couple of times to bring the dialog into view) to quickly test on other machines. It has 3x3 flashing squares which help you see if frames are being skipped or not.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn\`t compile it yesterday. But anyway, you seem to have solved the problem yourself, so the bounty is not rightfully mine. Please answer your own question (it\`s both permitted and encouraged) for the benefit of anyone who might be pulling the hair out in search of an answer for this very problem =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that when `CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_INTEROP_USER_SYNC` is false then manual synchronisation with `clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects` and `clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects` is unneeded, except for one `clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects` call after the initialisation of the OpenGL texture. In that case it seems that `glFinish` is the only needed form of synchronisation.